# Could not deploy React app from Visual studio Code to azure App service

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I am trying to deploy a simple React app to Azure App Service from Visual Studio Code using AzureAppService extension. However it was failed with the error: Couldn't detect a version for the platform 'nodejs' in the repo. the node version on both local machine and Azure Web App is 16.

Any idea please?

```
9:10:47 pm spa1234: Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform nodejs --platform-version 16 -p virtualenv_name= --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log -i /tmp/8dab4f80016b776 -p compress_node_modules=tar-gz | tee /tmp/oryx-build.log
9:10:53 pm spa1234: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
9:10:53 pm spa1234: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
9:10:53 pm spa1234: Oryx Version: 0.2.20220812.1, Commit: cdf6b1b, ReleaseTagName: 20220812.1
9:10:53 pm spa1234: Build Operation ID: |75RCaacLtWg=.52a37c81_
9:10:53 pm spa1234: Repository Commit : 745ee158-98c2-4cb4-8cba-c067ab33681a
9:10:53 pm spa1234: Detecting platforms...
9:10:53 pm spa1234: Could not detect any platform in the source directory.
9:10:53 pm spa1234: Error: Couldn't detect a version for the platform 'nodejs' in the repo.
9:10:56 pm spa1234: /bin/bash -c "oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform nodejs --platform-version 16 -p virtualenv_name= --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log -i /tmp/8dab4f80016b776 -p compress_node_modules=tar-gz | tee /tmp/oryx-build.log ; exit $PIPESTATUS "
9:10:56 pm spa1234: Generating summary of Oryx build
9:10:56 pm spa1234: Parsing the build logs
9:10:56 pm spa1234: Found 0 issue(s)
9:10:56 pm spa1234: Build Summary :
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion here is to make the `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT= FALSE` it should work.